# *ngIf How to set a local angular variable inside list and use it outside list iteration ends

Tags: angular

I have this code where if a record has baseline=1, I want to set a variable that there is presence of baseline in the list and use it outside the table. How to do it? I need #noBaseline option only when there is no record with baseline=1

```
<tr class="mat-row" *ngFor="let markup of markups">
    <td class="mat-cell">{{markup.category}}</td>
    <td class="mat-cell">{{markup.markup_percent}}</td>
    <td class="mat-cell">{{markup.markup_flatrate}}</td>
     <td class="mat-cell"><span *ngIf="markup.baseline else noBaseline"> Default Markup </span></td>
     <td class="mat-cell"><button  mat-icon-button matSuffix>
   <mat-icon [routerLink]="[markup.id]">edit</mat-icon>
  </button> <button (click)="deleteMarkup(markup.client_name,markup.id)"  mat-icon-button matSuffix>
    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
  </button></td>
  </tr>

<ng-template #noBaseline >
  <mat-card >
    
    <h2>No Default Markup is present </h2>
    <div>This is the global markup setting. Any product that does not match a specific markup rule will use these values. </div>
    <br />
     <button mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="add-default-markup"><mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon> Add Default Markup</button>
   </mat-card>
  </ng-template>
```

If I use #noBaseline in ng-template it shows within the table where baseline is 0 for all the other rows.
How to use noBaseline outside the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the condition for each row and want to show the no baseline for those row then you can simply add another column and show that optionally:

```
    <table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">category</th>
  <th scope="col">percent</th>
  <th scope="col">flatrate</th>
  <th scope="col">baseline</th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="mat-row" *ngFor="let markup of markups">
<td class="mat-cell">{{markup.category}}</td>
<td class="mat-cell">{{markup.markup_percent}}</td>
<td class="mat-cell">{{markup.markup_flatrate}}</td>
 <td class="mat-cell">
<span *ngIf="markup.baseline"> 
Default 
 Markup </span>
</td>
<td class="mat-cell">
 <span *ngIf="markup.baseline != 1"> 
 <mat-card >
<h2>No Default Markup is present </h2>
<div>This is the global markup setting. Any product that does not match a 
specific markup rule will use these values. </div>
<br/>
 <button mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="add-default-markup"> 
<mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon> Add Default Markup</button>
</mat-card> </span></td>
<td class="mat-cell"><button  mat-icon-button matSuffix>
<mat-icon [routerLink]="[markup.id]">edit</mat-icon>
</button> <button (click)="deleteMarkup(markup.client_name,markup.id)"  
mat-icon-button matSuffix>
<mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That doesnt help @pallavi. It makes the template for noBaseline to appear on every row where baseline =0. I want to use it outside the table.

Comment: @smiti I have updated my answer, you can try it as an alternative if suits your requirement

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining the question properly. There can be only one row with markup.baseline=1. My condition is that when there is even one row where baseline =1 and rest all others have baseline 0, I want a functionality in another div, where I want the user to add markup with baseline=1 (the div with #noBaseline). I dont want to give this functionality in other rows of the table. This div of noBaseline is independent of the table and should be present only if there is not even a single row with baseline=1. Your code places this div on each row of baseline = 0.